# Distinct combination of two columns with ordering from a third column?

Tags: sqlite

Lets say I have the following table:

```
col1        col2        diff
ABC         XYZ         1.2
FOO         BAR         5.0
FOO         BAR         0.0
ABC         XYZ         1.3
```

Now I want to get unique combinations of `col1` and `col2`, but for each combination I only want the one that has the lowest `diff`. So the result I'm looking for is this:

```
col1        col2        diff
ABC         XYZ         1.2
FOO         BAR         0.0
```

I could do either `DISTINCT col1, col2` or `GROUP BY col1, col2`, but how do I make sure I get the combination that has the lowest `diff`?

Answer (score 0):

Try aggregating by `col1` and `col2` and select the minimum value of `diff`:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, MIN(diff) AS diff
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```